# Looking for a way to automate mapping user credentials for DataStage users

Tags: command-line-interface, datastage

We currently follow a slightly modified series of steps--called [mapping user credentials](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.moz.wc.admin.doc/topics/wsisinst_config_user_mappings.html)--to give a user access to DataStage. We have to follow these steps on multiple servers.

There are a lot of shell scripts and binaries in the installed directories, but they don't seem to be documented except in passing

I'd like to automate this if I can, but I can't find a cli that will let me talk to IIS' components. Can someone point me to a cli that will do this, or documentation on the various scripts and binaries found in the install directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **DirectoryCommand -add_ds_credentials**

[IBM Knowledge Center article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.found.admin.common.doc/topics/directorycommand_tool.html)

Comment: Thank you. That worked in the sandbox, not we just got to get to work in all the different environments. Whee!